# Server-side versus Client-side Chart generation

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I have to choose a tool to generate Graphs with information about time consumption, project time distribution and so..
I'm currently using PHP and I was wondering what are the pros and cons between client-side chart generation (such as [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/)) and server-side (like [PChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)). Any suggestion?

Comment: http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/03/javascript-charts-using-php-and-mysql-with-fusioncharts-xt-part-2/

Answer (score 4):

The server gives you tighter control - relying on the client assumes that a) the user has JS enabled, and b) there isn't something wonky with their browser.

However, doing it on the client means less resources spent on your server. That might be important for you, or it might not.

Answer (score 2):

Well server side computational power is being used.  If you pay for CPU usage or have limited cpu usage phcarts could hurt.

Javascript charts are backend agnostic.  They are lightweight, put the burden of rendering on the user and are very lush colorful and interactive.